# Window Trim Removal Stucco Plaster

Tags: trim

I'm considering updating the window trim on my house but can't tell if the trim will come off easily or not. The windows were replaced about 20+ years ago but I'm not sure if the trim is the orignal trim or not.

Based on the photo, shows the window and also a close up of the trim, can anyone tell if the trim is embedded in the stucco/plaster? I don't want to remove it if it would require me doing a bunch of stucco patching.

Late 1940s Bay Area house with stucco/plaster exterior siding.

Thanks[image]

Comment: The windows appear to be "replacement" windows set in the old framing, to me.

Answer (score 2):

If the stucco is the real 1940s stucco, which there is no reason to think it is the modern day equivalent of what is considered stucco, the trim will be imbedded, or so it should be.

The only issue with what I see in the picture, and a closeup would be needed to confirm, is how the side trim meets the sill. The side trim should not be overhanging the sill. It suggests the side trim was added later, but it was done a lonnnnng time ago from what the paint layers look like. Even if it was added after the stucco was done you will be contending with the line left over from the edge where the trim used to be, unless you replace the trim with the same width piece or wider.

The problem will be if you are replacing all the window trim around the house. There will be flashing at the top of the window that will quite compromised if the trim is taken out from under it. If it is just the window or windows on the porch where the rain will never hit the top, the flashing or lack of it will be no concern.

Comment: Thanks Jack. This window is covered by an overhang, but based on your helpful information I think I'll leave it as is.